# finding nearst user using FireBase(thinking of geofire?)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to find the nearest user to each user which is online,
this is my firebase database:

[image: database]

This is my `MainActivity` `onCreate` function which is getting the data:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // Set default username is anonymous.
    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
        // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;
    } else {
        mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
        if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        }
    }

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
        .addApi(AppInvite.API)
        .build();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    double lat = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
    double lang = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("latitude").setValue(lat);
    mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("longitude").setValue(lang);
    mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Availability").setValue(true);
    mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Availability").onDisconnect().setValue(false);

    FirebaseOptions options = new     FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApplicationId("geofire").setDatabaseUrl(GEO_FIRE_DB).build();
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options);
    // setup GeoFire
    this.geoFire = new     GeoFire(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app).getReferenceFromUrl(GEO_FIRE_REF));
}
```

I'm new in Android development and it's my first real application, my next mission is to use the information stored in the database so each user can get connected with the nearest user. How can I do it? I thought about creating hash with all distance of user and save it in user via `SharedPreferences`.

Please help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Since you're already thinking of using GeoFire, I recommend checking out the documentation: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#getting-started-with-firebase. It'll show you how to [insert your users into a Geoindex](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#setting-location-data) (really just a separate node in your Firebase Database that has the user's key and a Geohash) and how to [query for nearby users](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#geo-queries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do

```
Location currentLocation = new Location();     
currentLocation.setLatitude(CURRENT_USER_LAT); 
currentLocation.setLongitude(CURRENT_USER_LNG);
Location compareLoc = new Location();
float minDist = Float.MAX_VALUE;
float distance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_LOCATIONS; i++)
{
    compareLoc.setLatitude(LOCATIONS[i].lat); 
    compareLoc.setLongitude(LOCATIONS[i].lng);
    distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(compareLoc);
    if(distance<minDist) {
        //THIS IS THE ENTRY WITH THE MINIMUM DISTANCE.
        //DO WITH IT AS YOU PLEASE
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a few questions,1. at new Location(), i need to insert "" right?(it need a string),2.CURRENT_USER_LAT suppost to be the lat variable at my code? , how do i get TOTAL_LOCATIONS via my firebase data?(seems as a list which i need to create? how?)

Comment: 1. Yeah! You need to give it a string. Consider giving it some string like "Location 1" and "Compare Location" or something like that. In reality, that string is totally pointless.
2. Yes
3. Not sure how you return locations from FireBase, but I think it should be a fairly straightforward query.

Finally, there is something to consider when it comes to this point: think about Facebook doing this to figure out who is the nearest. They can't!! It's TOO HUGE and it would take forever to calculate on the user's device! Therefore, I don't recommend you do on the client side. Try service side.